# Weak and strong convergence of operator sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Let $|e|\leq1$ such that $e\neq0$,  we define the lineal operator $F_e: C^1([-1,1],R)\rightarrow R $ as $$ F_e x(t) =\frac{x(e) - x(-e)} {2 e} . $$
I need to know if the sequence of operators ${\{F_e\} }_e$  converges weakly and/or strongly to some operator as $e\rightarrow0$.
I suspect that limit could be $x'(0)$ but Idk  how to prove it or disprove it.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you,  that will help me to learn the basics.